# Ninject Request Scope and spawned thread

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, nhibernate, ninject

I have my MVC app configured with Ninject and NHibernate. I have some requests that come in and all they do is queue up some work, fire up a thread to process the queue and then return.

I have my NHibernate session set to ReqeustScope. now my question is, does Ninject kill my Session object as soon as the request is ended? Or will it keep it around for the spawned threads?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with NInject but if it works like other DI containers I'd expect your session to be unavailable once the request is terminated.  If you need to run the background process in the same app domain you might consider providing two paths for resolving ISessions, one using ThreadScope for your background threads to access, and another using RequestScope for the web portion of the app.  Just make sure to be careful if you need to pass entities retrieved using the web session onto the background thread.

If you can split your background processes onto another app domain you could also create a custom scope that checks for an HttpContext and then decides which scope to use.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, Ninject will attempt to deactivate the session object at some point after the HttpContext is garbage collected. See this blog post:

http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20/